# Context API updating state causes looped requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have some context. I store there user roles.

```
const RolesContext = createContext({roles: []});
function RolesContextProvider({children}) {
  const [roles, setRoles] = useState([]);

  async function check(newRoles) {
    const missing = compareArrayWithArray(newRoles, roles);
    if (missing.length !== 0) {
      await User.roles(newRoles).then(((res) => {
        const updatedRoles = roles.concat(res.data);
        setRoles(updatedRoles);
      }));
    }
  }

  const defaultContext = {
    roles,
    check,
  };

  return (
    <RolesContext.Provider value={defaultContext}>
      {children}
    </RolesContext.Provider>
  );
}
export {RolesContext, RolesContextProvider};
```

When initiating component I run check roles

```
export default function Users() {
  const UsersComposition = compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
  )(ConnectedUsers);
  const context = useContext(RolesContext);
  const {roles, check} = context;
  useEffect(() => {
    check(['roles', 'to', 'check']);
  }, [check]);
  return <UsersComposition roles={roles}/>;
};
```

What it does...App is crashing due to inifite update state loop. It makes dozens of same requests with same payload. How it should be done? Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: You opened the `Context.Provider` component but you failed to close it.  You closed it with a `</RolesContext.Provider>` instead.

Comment: No, no...I was editing names and forgot about it.

Comment: This line right here: `const updatedRoles = roles.concat(res.data);` try to use the `spread` operator instead:  `const updatedRoles = [ ...roles, ...res.data ];`

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't help. `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the infinite loop you'll need to preserve `check` function's identity between renders. One way to do this is to save it with `useRef` (you'll need to pass existing roles as the second parameter):

```
const check = useRef(async (newRoles, roles) => {
    ...
});

const defaultContext = {
    roles,
    check: check.current,
};
```

You may also consider implementing `Users` as a class component and call `check` in `componentDidMount`:

```
class Users extends React.Component {
    static contextType = RolesContext;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.context.check(['roles', 'to', 'check']);
    }

    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated my code. Unfortunately I can't leave empty deps, It still causes looped requests.

Comment: I have edited edited my answer to match the updated question description

Comment: That's almost done...the least thing is that `useRef` clears value of  `roles` in `RolesProvider` on each call. Can I store it there somehow?

Comment: Yes, I see, it's because the function stored with `useRef` references `roles` from the closure created on the initial render. To overcome this, you can pass existing roles as the second parameter to the function. I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're calling `check` in a loop. See if I'm right.

- `RolesContextProvider` provides the context `roles` and `check`
- `Users` access the context and calls `check`
- `Check` updates `roles` in `RolesContextProvider` with `setRoles`
- `setRoles` triggers update in `RolesContextProvider` which changes the context
- And the context change updates `Users`
- And the cycle repeats

Comment: Exactly, but idk how to stop _listening_ to RolesContextProvider when `roles` didn't change compared to prev value.

Comment: `roles` is an array, which means it's stored as a reference and not a value. If you let it be recreated on every render, its reference will change even though its contents may be the same. The same goes for your `check` function. It's also stored as reference and it will change whenever it is recreated.

Comment: For the `check` function, you should take a look into `useCallback`. As for the `roles` array, you could use a `useRef` to keep the last array value and compare with the new one. If it has changed, update it and provide the new one. If it hasn't change, don't update it and provide the last one that you've kept inside the `useRef`. That's one possible solution. But I think you might check if you can't redesign your component's hierarchy. It might get simpler.